# Angular converting my date into datetime but in my database is only date

Tags: mysql, angular, typescript

I got in my database ( mysql )
column named: **check_in**
and format is **just: date**
and row got data: `2020-09-02`
When I am making call to my api I got output like:

```
"check_in":"2020-09-01T22:00:00.000Z"

SELECT check_in from accident_form where id = 76
```

phpmyadmin gives me correct: 2020-09-02

Why Angular converting my date into datetime?

Also I got one day befor not excatly day I want.

How should I format it to get correct date from DB?

Added backend

```
AccidentForm.findById = (id, reservation, result) => {
  sql.query(`SELECT accident_form.id, accident_form.check_in FROM accident_form WHERE accident_form.id = ${id} AND accident_form.reservation = '${reservation}'`, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("error: ", err);
      result(err, null);
      return;
    }

    if (res.length) {
      console.log("found accident form: ", res);
      result(null, res);
      return;
    }

    result({ kind: "not_found" }, null);
  });
};
```

Comment: Javascript is always using the local timezone for dates. So you might have UTC on your DB server (or whatever) what will lead to be a 2 hours earlier as your local time. So you get the previous day 22:00. I do not know how you get the date in Angular but in Javascript you normally have to work with the UTC date functions to get the right date.

Comment: I don't think angular will convert the date to datetime, while angular is a frontend framework where we just receive the data from backend. Can you post the code of your api pls?

Comment: @tengdaSU added

Comment: @MarkeZ It seems correct, could you post also the result of query and the code of angular where u get and use the data ?

Comment: @tengdaSU I used moments and converting it

Comment: @MarkeZ according to the large bundle size of moment.js,  I suggest u to use day.js. take a look at https://github.com/you-dont-need/You-Dont-Need-Momentjs